# How to pass to a server a query string got from other site

Tags: c#, query-string

my problem is that I need to post to a server exactly the same querystring I'm getting from a payment gateway. I've been trying different ways

```
        requestUrl = "Serveraddress.asp?";
        requestUrl += "orderKey=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(orderKey);
        requestUrl += "&paymentStatus=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(paymentStatus);
        requestUrl += "&paymentAmount=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(paymentAmount);
        requestUrl += "&paymentCurerncy=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(paymentCurrency);
        requestUrl += "&mac=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(mac);
        requestUrl += "&source=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(source);
```

Or

```
        var queryString = Request.QueryString.ToString();
```

or

```
        var query = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(queryString);
```

But none of them worked, how could I get this to do so?

Thanks in advance

UPDATE

I've changed that to

```
        requestUrl = "Serveraddress.asp?";
        requestUrl += "orderKey=" + orderKey;
        requestUrl += "&paymentStatus=" + paymentStatus;
        requestUrl += "&paymentAmount=" + paymentAmount;
        requestUrl += "&paymentCurerncy=" + paymentCurrency;
        requestUrl += "&mac=" + mac;
        requestUrl += "&source=" + source;
```

But I'm still getting the error 
    Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0005'
    Invalid procedure call or argument: "let"
    /xBooking/SVRWP/booking.inc, line 930

My concern is that the orderKey parameter is the kind of SUPPLIER^AIRWEB^F66257-1241186 and I don't really know if this needs to be encoded (visually the url seems to be fine without any encoding).

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using correct HTTP METHOD?

Comment: have you tried not encoding the querystring at all? Some payment gateways don't try decoding the url they receive, so they don't like it encoded (even if it's theoretically the right thing to do...)

Comment: How do you mean "haven't worked"? Are you receiving an error message?

Comment: Not a specific error, just a 500 one. I'm gonna try withouth encoding it at all.

Comment: Actually I think the problem is with this ^ symbols, that are present in one of the fields